# Typeset Theorems in Upright Fonts for Beamer

Tags: beamer, theorems

I want to typeset my theorems within my presentation in upright fonts. The only way I know is by doing this:

```
\begin{theorem}
\textup{Upright Theorem}
\end{theorem}
```

When I use `article` document class, I can use the theorem package and type `\theorembodyfont{\upshape}` within the preamble. However, such thing did not work for Beamer. I would like to do the similar thing when I use beamer (defined the upright-ness within the preamble). Is it possible?

Answer (score 13):

You can look at section `Theorem Environments` in beamer manual and there you will find how to do it.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[normal font]
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{theorem}
This is a theorem
\end{theorem}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to number the theorems and keep them in regular font, you can do so. Please see [Beamer: Typesetting theorems in upright font *and* numbering them](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/502231/beamer-typesetting-theorems-in-upright-font-and-numbering-them)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]
\addtobeamertemplate{theorem begin}{\normalfont}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}[This should be numbered]
This should be upright.
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```