# Beamer: Typesetting theorems in upright font *and* numbering them

Tags: beamer, theorems

I want to number my theorems and typeset them in the upright font. I know there are the options "numbered" and "normal font" for the theorem template, but I can't use both at the same time.

Is there some way I can use the "ams style" option and change the ams style for theorem to upright font? I haven't managed to get this working either.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[normal font]

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[This should be numbered]

This should be upright.

\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There does not seem to be an existing style for this. But since the code difference between `numnbered` and `normal font` is not that big. This seems to work

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]
\addtobeamertemplate{theorem begin}{\normalfont}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[This should be numbered]

This should be upright.

\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly!

Comment: @Jan remember to click the check mark on an answer if it is what you ended up using